# Label on top of TextInput text

Tags: react-native

I'm new to `react-native-material` and I have the label text on top of the input text [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61c2r.png) when I use the :

```js
<View style={styles.layout} >
  <TextInput label="Email" variant="outlined" style={styles.textInput} />
<View/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  layout: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center", 
    alignItems: "center", 
    width: "100%"
  },
  textInput:{
    width: "80%", 
    marginVertical: 10
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

I expect the label to stay on top as long as the there's an input in the `TextInput`

Comment: I tried your code on my set up, and it worked for me without issue. You can clean your project (use [this tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project)), reinstall everything, and try again. The problem might go away.